# Alternative keyboard with Czech language dictionary?

Tags: keyboard, 2.1-eclair, languages, localization

Is there any alternative keyboard for Android HTC Desire 2.1 that supports English/Czech dictionary and easy way to switch between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went for [SwiftKey](http://swiftkey.net/). Still waiting for Czech language dictionary though :-)

Comment: Czech dict is available for SwiftKey now :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can install HTC_IME modified http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=624416 and make a gesture for cycling between EN / CZ.

Answer (score 0):

I am happy with Smart Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

[AnySoftKeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard&hl=en_US) is a free application with many keyboard layouts and themes, and after installing it you may download langue pack for many languages, including the Czech one (or directly from Google Play - [Czech for AnySoftKeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.herrlado.ask.languagepack.czech&hl=en_US)).

Czech dictionary from AOSP has more than 100,000 words. English langue pack with English dictionary is included by default.

[image]